# How to deal with "#" in a query string in mod_rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640977/how-to-redirect-old-ugly-urls-to-seo-friendly-ones) about rewriting old "ugly" links into seo friendly ones.

I need to "extract" some information after the "sharp" symbol in some urls. I've created a regular expression to it but it can't seen to work.

After my question, I created this logic for this url for example, `script.php?mode=full&id=23`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /script\.php\?mode=full&id=([0-9]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^script\.php$ fix_old_urls.php?phpfile=script2&id=%1 [NC,L]
```

But I'm working in a legacy application, and I need to extract the value after the sharp symbol in some pages, in the example url `script.php?mode=full#23`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /script\.php\?mode=list\#([0-9]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^script\.php$ fix_old_urls.php?phpfile=script&id=%1 [NC,L]
```

(in fix_old_urls I properly redirect with a 301 code).

The first one works, but not the second. To me it looks like it`s the same logic in both. What am I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anchor information (the part starting with the `#`) is *never actually sent to the server*. It's handled completely by the browser, and thus you can't touch it with mod_rewrite (nor can you access it via server-side scripting languages). The only things that can see it are the browser and client-side scripts (like Javascript).