# IE 7/8 removes everything after hash mark when redirected after file upload

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

Consider the following situation. User submits a form which contains a file input field. Then, after processing the upload, server redirects browser to the address containing `#hash-part`. If the browser is IE7/8, it will discard the part after hash mark (including the `#` itself). Moreover, it will do this irrespective of whether actual file upload took place or user just left the file field empty. The following code illustrates it.

```
<?  if (isset($_POST['sent'])) {
        header("Location: " . basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "#test");
        die();
    }
?><!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="sent" value="1" />
        <input type="file" name="test" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

After form is submitted, IE 7/8 shows the same address in the address bar as before while other browsers (and IE 9/10) get properly redirected to the index.php#test. When the file input is replaced with text input, the problem is gone.

Is it a bug or some kind of security measure? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436742/retain-anchor-when-redirecting-subdomain-ie

Comment: Thanks, but that's a different issue.

Comment: can you give an example for the full url as in `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: http://dan.in.ua/iebug/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using double redirect on IE 7/8. I replaced

```
header("Location: " . basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "#test");
```

with

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match('/(^|[^a-zA-Z])(MSIE|msie) [678]($|[^\d])/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) // If IE 6, 7 or 8
    header("Location: redirect.php?to=" . urlencode(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "#test"));
else    // For sane browsers
    header("Location: " . basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "#test");
```

and created a simple redirection script `redirect.php`:

```
<?  if (isset($_GET['to']))
        header('Location: ' . $_GET['to']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats an odditiy of internet explroer I had to deal with when implementing an oauth flow with javascript.

It appears that it is possible to work around the problem by placing a trailing slash directly in front of the hashtag. so instead of `file.php#werewwer` make `file.php/#werwer`

However I do not know why... I think its a bug.

The hashtag is intendeed to never be trasmitted to the server. It is client side only. I think IE just removes it early...

Another possibility is to use a meta redirect instead of a header redirect. That seems to work. You can also append to the url using javascript... Dont know whether this is suitable in your use case.