# htaccess RewriteRule with hard-coded special characters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are a lot of similar questions, but none of them seem to deal with hard-coded strings in the destination. I merely want to redirect any requests for a sub-domain to a Google Group, such as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} gg.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/myforum
```

I believe the problem is that the **#** character is being interpreted as a comment and thus the line is ignored. I have looked through the [documentation for rewrite flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html), and the only options I saw which might be relevant were [B] and [NE], neither of which seem to help, as I think they only work on string transformations.

Comment: Anchor information (the part starting with the `#`) is never actually sent to the server. It's handled completely by the browser, and thus you can't touch it with `mod_rewrite` (nor can you access it via server-side scripting languages). The only things that can see it are the browser and client-side scripts (like Javascript). Extracted from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1665209/3648578

Comment: @kmsdev Since the `#` character is in the rewritten part, it works as expected. Google uses client-sided scripting to figure out what is behind the `#`, and loads the correct forum based on that.

Answer (score 0):

The `#` character in your url should not be treated as a comment (it isn't for me). If it is treated as such though, you can escape it to let it loose it's special meaning. Escaping is the act of puting a `\` before a character. Besides that, you require the `[NE]` flag to prevent the `#` from being ascii encoded.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} gg.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://groups.google.com/forum/\#!forum/myforum [NE]
```

Comment: Same problem, my host (powweb) is ignoring the line and returning a 404. I have 10 other identical re-writes, but the destination URL doesn't include # or ! characters.

Comment: Then you might not have put this in the directory gg.domain.com is linked to, or your host does something weird with `%{HTTP_HOST}`. What happens if you change the rewriterule to `RewriteRule foo /bar?the_request=%{THE_REQUEST}&http_host=%{HTTP_HOST} [R,L]`. Then go to gg.domain.com/foo and look at the resulting url.

Comment: I assume it's in the right directory because other redirects for the same domain work fine. Copy/pasting that line returns `404` but this time it redirects to my 404 page defined in `htaccess` instead of redirecting to my provider's own 404 page. Without /foo it takes me to the root page (domain.com).

Comment: I would recommend talking to your hosting provider. I am unsure why this is happening.