# Adjusting dynamically generated links using .htaccess or any other method?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic, e-commerce

I have an e-commerce website (created with a ecommercetemplates shopping cart PHP template) and on the catalogue pages there are, at times, a few pages which are numbered at the bottom.  The links to these pages are, for example, in the form:- `/product.php?cat=27&pg=2` despite the main page having been mapped to:- `/widgets` using a rewrite rule in a .htaccess file.

For the sake of consistency and simplicity, I would like the pages to be as:- `/widgets?pg=2`.  I asked in this forum how to do this and found the following solution:-

```
RewriteRule ^widgets$ products.php?cat=27 [QSA]
```

The problem is that despite the above rewrite rule working as I wanted, the current links on the catalogue page still point to, for example:- `/product.php?cat=27&pg=2`.  In order to go to `/widgets?pg=2`, I have to enter this in the browser.

So my question is: How do I change the current links on the catalogue page, which are dynamically generated?  Are there any further rules which can be entered in .htaccess or is there any other solution to this problem?  The following is the PHO code for the product page:- http://freetexthost.com/3ubiydspzm.

In the link above, if you do a search for 'writepagebar', I think this is where the 'next page', 'previous page', and the 'page numbers' are done.

Comment: I can tell you that this cannot be done with `.htaccess`/`mod_rewrite` - those are only for changing the URL that the browser has actually requested. What you are trying to do is change the _contents_ of an HTML page, and to do that you will need to change the contents of the PHP file. It would help if you can identify the part of the PHP file that corresponds to the link to `/product.php?cat=27&pg=2`.

Comment: Well if you look at the 'freetexthost' link:- http://freetexthost.com/3ubiydspzm.  On that page if you do a search for 'writepagebar', I think this is where the 'next page', 'previous page', and the 'page numbers' are done.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

Most of them require more than just .htaccess rewrite rules.

- You can modify the writepagebar function to output the friendly URL for you. (And change any other function that might link to this products page.)
- You can buffer the entire page's output and do a string replace on it. (See ob_start and ob_get_clean in the PHP manual.)
- You can redirect ugly URLs to pretty ones with a 301 redirect. (The links will stay the same, but your friendly URLs get the SEO credit and show up in the browser.)
- - You can do it any of these ways: [How to redirect old "ugly" urls to seo-friendly ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640977/how-to-redirect-old-ugly-urls-to-seo-friendly-ones)
- - Or you can try this ugly mod_rewrite hack that I can't guarantee will work on your server or with your application.

Hack:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(cat=27\&)(.*) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(cat=27)(.*)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !widgets
RewriteRule ^products.php$ widgets?%1%3 [R=301,L]
```

(This might need the rewrite base option)
`http://services.rrbits.com/products.php?cat=27&pg=2` (Example link.)

Comment: I thought adjusting the writepagebar function might be worth a try.  Any ideas how to adjust it to get the result that I want?  I've posted the code in one of the answers.